# Processing SOAP request with Content-Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Java

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a SOAP client sending through a request with it's Content-Type defined as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. My jax-ws server responds with a HTTP 415 error complaining that it expects a content-type of text/xml.

Evidently this client cannot be changed so am trying to find out if there is anyway to force my server to accept this content-type?

Comment: Your client is not a SOAP client so youer server is right to reject the request.

Comment: Just what are they sending in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request? A mis-labelled SOAP request, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Tichodrama was right.  The client was not a soap client.  It was instead sending xml over HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and finally i had to add a servlet that accepts Content-Type defined as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and internally this servlet invokes all the SOAP logic behind.